# How to Check Application idle for MVC application

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, session

I know that similar thing is asked for WPF application but I want to know is there anyway to find out the application idle time for an MVC application so that I can show the session timeout popup like banking websites.
I currently searched on websites and I found this link:
http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/aspnet/archive/2011/06/15/asp-net-how-to-show-a-popup-warning-before-session-timeout.aspx

But if anyone could share better solution, it would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

They typically just start a javascript timer, then after it times out, they just redirect to the logout page.  It's actually quite simple, but it has nothing to do with the actual apps idle timeout.

You can add a nifty gui to it, but it's not particularly difficult.